# Wix: User Interface WixUI_FeatureTree add control to Welcome Dialog

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I'm using WiX installer and WixUI_FeatureTree UI. I want to customize the Welcome Dialog window by adding one more text control. How can I do that? I search the documentation and didn't find anything

I that is not possible then can I change the height of the "Description" control? I tried like this but the Height was not changed?

```
<UI>
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Description" Property="Height" Value="150"></Publish>
</UI>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new control would require replacing the entire dialog and re-wiring the UI sequences to get your dialog to show up instead. You can read about that here: [Customizing Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html).

If you just want to extend the contents of a control, WiX v3.6 has a new feature that allows .wxl files to not only change the text of a control but to change it's coordinates as well. Bob Arnson has a good article on that here: [Localizing more than strings in WiX v3.6](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/).

Comment: Thank you! The article from Bob Arnson help me and pointed me in right direction.